# How to read tables from synapse database tables using pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-synapse

I am a newbie to Azure Synapse, I have to work on the Azure spark notebook. One of my colleagues connected the on-prime database using the azure link service. Now I have written a test framework for comparing the on-prime data and data-lake(curated) data. but I don't understand how to read those tables using Pyspark.
here is my linked service data structure.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muXce.png)

here my Link service names and Database name.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can read any file as a table which is stored in Synapse Linked location by using Azure Synapse Dedicated SQL Pool Connector for Apache Spark.

First you need to read the file which you need to read as the table in Synapse. Use below code to read the file.

```
%%pyspark
df = spark.read.load('abfss://sampleadls2@sampleadls1.dfs.core.windows.net/business.csv', format='csv', header=True)
```

Then convert this file into table using the code below:

```
%%pyspark
spark.sql("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS business")
df.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("business.data")
```

Refer below image.

[image]

Now you can run any Spark SQL command on this table as shown below:

```
%%pyspark
data = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM business.data") 
display(data)
```

See the output in below image.

[image]

Comment: My Data is in SQL Database not in a storage account and I don't know to give the link service name, please I see I have updated the names and database name, please check it.